# TeamCity not checking out latest commits from Subversion

Tags: caching, svn, teamcity, svn-checkout

I've added an app.config to a project, but when I run the build agent, it's not picking up that file.  I have Clean all files before build checked, and have tried both checkout modes (automatically on server, and automatically on agent).

Here's the log file:

```
[17:24:50]: Skip checking for changes - changes are already collected
[17:24:51]: Clean build enabled: removing old files from C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce
[17:24:51]: Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[17:24:51]: Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce
[17:24:51]: Updating sources: server side checkout... (1s)
[17:24:52]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Will perform clean checkout
[17:24:52]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Clean checkout reasons
[17:24:52]: [Clean checkout reasons] Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
[17:24:52]: [Clean checkout reasons] "Clean all files before build" turned on
[17:24:52]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Building clean patch for VCS root: BruteForce
[17:24:52]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Transferring cached clean patch for VCS root: BruteForce
[17:24:52]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Repository sources transferred: 84.54Kb total
[17:24:52]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Removing C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce
[17:24:52]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Updating C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce
[17:24:55]: Project "BruteForce.sln.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (TeamCity_Generated_Build target(s)): (9s)
[17:24:55]: [Project "BruteForce.sln.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (TeamCity_Generated_Build target(s)):] Project "BruteForce.sln" (Rebuild target(s)): (9s)
[17:24:55]: [Project "BruteForce.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
[17:24:55]: [Project "BruteForce.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)): (7s)
[17:24:56]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Deleting file "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll".
[17:24:56]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Deleting file "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.pdb".
[17:24:56]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Deleting file "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\obj\Release\ResolveAssemblyReference.cache".
[17:24:56]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Deleting file "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\obj\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll".
[17:24:56]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Deleting file "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\obj\Release\NewVisionClasses.pdb".
[17:24:56]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Successfully cleaned the output for 0 EDMX files.
[17:24:56]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Processing 0 EDMX files.
[17:24:56]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Finished processing 0 EDMX files.
[17:24:56]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /reference:Logging\bin\log4net.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Management.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.ServiceProcess.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.Services.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vjslib.dll /debug:pdbonly /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll /target:library clsBruteMoverThread.cs clsByteConvert.cs clsCamData.cs clsCamDriveInfo.cs clsDeviceExtracter.cs clsExtracter.cs clsFileMoveInfo.cs clsFileMover.cs clsRegistry.cs clsRequestExtracter.cs clsSysCheck.cs clsVideoLog.cs clsXmlUtil.cs Connection\ConnBase.cs Connection\ConnClient.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\AdminConfig.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\AlertButton.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\AlertButtonList.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\AlertConnInfo.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\ClientAlert.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\ClientConfig.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\CommandName.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\GenericAlert.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\Packet.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\PacketColor.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\PacketColorList.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\PacketType.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\ReceiverConfig.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\ServerConfig.cs Connection\ConnectionClasses\StatusAlert.cs Connection\ConnectionInfo.cs Connection\ConnectionInfoList.cs Connection\ConnServer.cs Connection\ConnSocket.cs Connection\EventHandlers.cs Connection\RetryInfo.cs Connection\WSProxy.cs Data\Csv.cs delegate.cs FTP\FtpClient.cs FTP\FtpDeclaration.cs FTP\FtpEntry.cs FTP\FtpEntryCollection.cs FTP\FtpFactory.cs FTP\FtpProgressChanged.cs FTP\FtpProgressCompleted.cs FTP\FtpWorkerArgument.cs GUI\RichColorFormat.cs IO\FileBase.cs IO\ImageFile.cs IO\ImageFileList.cs IO\IndexFile.cs IO\IndexFileCreator.cs IO\ObjectSerializer.cs IO\PlayList.cs IO\PlayListFile.cs IO\PlayListItem.cs License\LicenseFactory.cs License\LicenseWrapper.cs Logging\Log4NetLogger.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Security\Security.cs Services\BGWorkerBase.cs Services\BruteFileInfo.cs Services\BruteForceProcess.cs Services\BruteForce\BFConfig.cs Services\BruteForce\BFProcess.cs Services\BruteForce\BFService.cs Services\IService.cs Services\VideoMaintenance\MaintConfig.cs Services\MaintDayProcess.cs Services\SaveSegment\ClipGenerator.cs Services\SaveSegment\SSConfig.cs Services\SaveSegment\SSProcess.cs Services\SaveSegment\SSService.cs Services\ServiceBase.cs Services\VideoMaintenance\ActivityLogMaintenance.cs Services\VideoMaintenance\FileMaintenanceBase.cs Services\VideoMaintenance\ServiceLogMaintenance.cs Services\VideoMaintenance\VideoMaintenanceManager.cs Services\VideoMaintenance\VideoMaintProcess.cs Simulation\Camera\CamSim.cs Simulation\Camera\CamSimDeclare.cs Simulation\Camera\MassCamera.cs Simulation\Camera\MassCamera2.cs Simulation\Camera\MassVirtualCamera.cs Simulation\Camera\VirtualCamera.cs Utilities\CamDriveInfo.cs Utilities\Compression\ZipEntryCS.cs Utilities\Compression\ZipFileCS.cs Utilities\ErrorMessage.cs Utilities\Extensions.cs Utilities\FolderDayCleaner.cs Utilities\FolderMonitor.cs Utilities\FolderMonitor2.cs Utilities\ParentFolderDayCleaner.cs Utilities\Parser.cs Utilities\ProgressReport.cs Utilities\SearchPattern.cs Utilities\StringFormat\StringFormater.cs Utilities\StringFormat\StringTable.cs Utilities\StringFormat\StringTableColumn.cs Utilities\StringFormat\StringTableRow.cs Utilities\UrlLoopArgument.cs Utilities\UrlLooping.cs Utilities\Validator.cs Utilities\VisionServiceController.cs Utilities\Wallpaper.cs Web\HttpClient.cs Web\HttpConnection.cs Web\WebService\SOAPClient.cs Web\WebService\SOAPRequest.cs Web\WebService\SOAPResponse.cs WinSystem\Kernel32.cs Xml\NameValue.cs Xml\Web\CameraLoopItem.cs Xml\Web\CameraLoopList.cs Xml\Web\IndexCreator.cs Xml\Web\IndexFile.cs Xml\Web\IndexReader.cs Xml\Web\NavModule.cs Xml\Web\NavModuleList.cs Xml\Web\SegmentOrder.cs Xml\Web\SegmentOrderList.cs Xml\Web\UserManagerInfo.cs Xml\Web\UserManagerInfoList.cs Xml\Web\WebLocationItem.cs Xml\Web\WebLocationList.cs Xml\Web\WebMenuItem.cs Xml\Web\WebMenuItemList.cs Xml\XmlClasses\Announcement.cs Xml\XmlClasses\CamDev.cs Xml\XmlClasses\CamDevList.cs Xml\XmlClasses\CameraInfo.cs Xml\XmlClasses\CameraInfoList.cs Xml\XmlClasses\CiscoCamInfo.cs Xml\XmlClasses\MatrixPreset.cs Xml\XmlClasses\MatrixPresetList.cs Xml\XmlClasses\ServerDictionary.cs Xml\XmlClasses\ServerDictionaryItem.cs Xml\XmlClasses\ServerInfo.cs Xml\XmlClasses\ServerInfoList.cs Xml\XmlClasses\TextAnnounce.cs Xml\XmlClasses\UserDev.cs Xml\XmlClasses\UserInfo.cs Xml\XmlClasses\UserInfoList.cs Xml\XmlClasses\UserMod.cs Xml\XmlClasses\UserProfile.cs Xml\XmlClasses\UserProfileConfig.cs Xml\XmlData\CSVTable.cs Xml\XmlData\NameObject.cs Xml\XmlData\XmlDataSet.cs Xml\XmlData\XmlDataSource.cs Xml\XmlData\XmlTable.cs Xml\XmlData\XmlTableCollection.cs Xml\XmlNode.cs Xml\XmlObjectSerializer.cs Xml\XmlStreamBase.cs Xml\XmlStreamBaseList.cs Xml\XPathSelector.cs
[17:25:02]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "obj\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll" to "bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll".
[17:25:02]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] NewVisionClasses -> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll
[17:25:02]: [Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "obj\Release\NewVisionClasses.pdb" to "bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.pdb".
[17:25:02]: [Project "BruteForce.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
[17:25:02]: [Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Creating directory "obj\Release\".
[17:25:02]: [Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Successfully cleaned the output for 0 EDMX files.
[17:25:02]: [Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Processing 0 EDMX files.
[17:25:02]: [Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Finished processing 0 EDMX files.
[17:25:02]: [Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Creating directory "bin\Release\".
[17:25:03]: [Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /reference:"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.3\bin\net-2.0\framework\nunit.framework.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.ServiceProcess.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:"obj\Release\Brute Force tests.dll" /target:library BruteForceUnitTests.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
[17:25:03]: [Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "obj\Release\Brute Force tests.dll" to "bin\Release\Brute Force tests.dll".
[17:25:03]: [Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Brute Force tests -> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce\Brute Force tests\bin\Release\Brute Force tests.dll
[17:25:03]: [Project "Brute Force tests.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "obj\Release\Brute Force tests.pdb" to "bin\Release\Brute Force tests.pdb".
[17:25:03]: [Project "BruteForce.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
[17:25:03]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Creating directory "obj\Release\".
[17:25:03]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Creating directory "bin\Release\".
[17:25:03]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
[17:25:03]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
[17:25:03]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Processing resource file "frmMain.resx" into "obj\Release\BruteForce.frmMain.resources".
[17:25:03]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Processing resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" into "obj\Release\BruteForceGUI.Properties.Resources.resources".
[17:25:03]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Deployment.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /debug:pdbonly /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\BruteForceGUI.exe /resource:obj\Release\BruteForce.frmMain.resources /resource:obj\Release\BruteForceGUI.Properties.Resources.resources /target:winexe frmMain.cs frmMain.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll" to "bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll".
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.pdb" to "bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.pdb".
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce\BruteForceGUI\BFConfig.cfg.xml" to "bin\Release\BFConfig.cfg.xml".
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "obj\Release\BruteForceGUI.exe" to "bin\Release\BruteForceGUI.exe".
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] BruteForceGUI -> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce\BruteForceGUI\bin\Release\BruteForceGUI.exe
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceGUI.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "obj\Release\BruteForceGUI.pdb" to "bin\Release\BruteForceGUI.pdb".
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForce.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Creating directory "obj\Release\".
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Creating directory "bin\Release\".
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Processing resource file "ProjectInstaller.resx" into "obj\Release\srvBruteForce.ProjectInstaller.resources".
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Processing resource file "Service1.resx" into "obj\Release\srvBruteForce.Service1.resources".
[17:25:04]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /reference:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Configuration.Install.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.ServiceProcess.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /debug:pdbonly /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\BruteForceService.exe /resource:obj\Release\srvBruteForce.ProjectInstaller.resources /resource:obj\Release\srvBruteForce.Service1.resources /target:winexe Program.cs ProjectInstaller.cs ProjectInstaller.designer.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Service1.cs Service1.designer.cs
[17:25:05]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll" to "bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.dll".
[17:25:05]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\NewVisionClasses\NewVisionClasses\bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.pdb" to "bin\Release\NewVisionClasses.pdb".
[17:25:05]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "NewVisionClasses.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):
[17:25:05]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce\BruteForceService\BFConfig.cfg.xml" to "bin\Release\BFConfig.cfg.xml".
[17:25:05]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce\BruteForceService\_install.bat" to "bin\Release\_install.bat".
[17:25:05]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce\BruteForceService\_uninstall.bat" to "bin\Release\_uninstall.bat".
[17:25:05]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "obj\Release\BruteForceService.exe" to "bin\Release\BruteForceService.exe".
[17:25:05]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] BruteForceService -> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\BruteForce\BruteForceService\bin\Release\BruteForceService.exe
[17:25:05]: [Project "BruteForceService.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "obj\Release\BruteForceService.pdb" to "bin\Release\BruteForceService.pdb".
[17:25:05]: Publishing artifacts
[17:25:05]: [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [teamcity-info.xml]
[17:25:05]: [Publishing artifacts] Publishing files
[17:25:05]: Build finished
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not trying to patronize you, but have you used the SVN "add" command to be sure the file has been added to source control? I make that mistake all this time :)

Comment: Yeah, did a checkout myself to make sure the file is there.

Comment: I would double check the content of the repository with Tortoise, Repo-browser, make sure that the URL set on Teamcity is correct and, if everything seems ok, make teamcity run an empty task to make sure that there isn't some kinds of action deleting the app.config after SVN checkout ran.